# Extract results into pandas dataframe from large dataset in PySpark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

I am trying to extract some results (`sum()`, `avg()`) over a large dataset and it takes over a whole day to pass it to a pandas dataframe. The dataset is over 1000M rows, but the resulting dataframe should be ~80 rows as it is grouped by month and year for the last 3 years.

Right now I am extracting data as follows:

```py
df1 = sqlContext.sql('''
    SELECT DISTINCT year(date), month(date), sum(col1), sum(col2), avg(col3), count(col4)        
    FROM large_table
    WHERE // ...some filters
    GROUP BY year(date), month(date)
''')

df1.registerTempTable("df1")

# ...some PySpark operations

df1 = df1.toPandas()
```

I do not have much experience in PySpark. Should I be doing it some other way?

Comment: This looks right. Do you get an error? If it's too slow, try saving the Spark DataFrame to a parquet and loading it back in and something it's a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think removing the `DISTINCT` would be safe and could help. I try to think, but I don't see a scenario where `DISTINCT` would actually do something in the same query together with the aggregation.

Also, you may not need to do `df1.registerTempTable("df1")`. You could do Spark operations using PySpark syntax without registering the table.